# Cells with drag gesture overwrite the list scrolling using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI List with cells that are able to recognize drag gestures in order to swipe them.

The problem is that the drag gesture overlaps the scroll recognition of the list, so I only can swipe the cells. I can not scroll the list.

Is there a way in SwiftUI to tell the List that have to handle multiple gestures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `minimumDistance` to some value (for instance 30) on your cell item. Then the drag only works when you drag horizontally and reach the minimum distance, otherwise, the scrollview or list gesture override the view gesture

```swift
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .local))
```